# Getting invalid class name using reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

I am using java reflection in my code and iterating inside a class.
On iteration I am getting an invalid class name for a particular object.
PFB the code of reflection and the the logs i am getting.

**LOGGERS :**

```
2018-12-26 12:38:04,878 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- given class is : class com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping_$$_jvst3bb_5e
2018-12-26 12:38:04,879 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- fields are : private javassist.util.proxy.MethodHandler com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping_$$_jvst3bb_5e.handler
2018-12-26 12:38:04,879 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- fields are : public static byte[] com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping_$$_jvst3bb_5e._filter_signature
2018-12-26 12:38:04,879 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- fields are : public static final long com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping_$$_jvst3bb_5e.serialVersionUID
2018-12-26 12:38:04,879 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- fields are : private static java.lang.reflect.Method[] com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping_$$_jvst3bb_5e._methods_
2018-12-26 12:38:04,879 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- field is : handler path is : relatedBusinessSolutionMapping
2018-12-26 12:38:04,879 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- field is : _filter_signature path is : relatedBusinessSolutionMapping
2018-12-26 12:38:04,880 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- field is : serialVersionUID path is : relatedBusinessSolutionMapping
2018-12-26 12:38:04,880 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- field is : _methods_ path is : relatedBusinessSolutionMapping
2018-12-26 12:38:04,880 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- field is : solutionType path is : null
2018-12-26 12:38:04,880 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- Path in non-primitive type is : null for field : solutionType
```

As you can clearly see, the first line of logger prints class name as : `com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping_$$_jvst3bb_5e` 
which should instead be :

```
com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping
```

**Code for reflection :**

```
public static void setNullFieldInAnObject(Object object, Set<String> value, String path) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.info("In merge diff according to the given set function");
    LOGGER.info("Set is : " + value);
    LOGGER.info("Object is : " + object.toString());
    Class classA = object.getClass();
    LOGGER.info("given class is : " + classA.toString());
    Field fields[] = classA.getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        LOGGER.info("fields are : " + fields[i].toString());
    }
}
```

Only in this case **it gives a wrong class name which hinders me in iterating inside the class**.For all other cases,it's working fine.
Please help.

Comment: Could it be that this class is an anonymous class? --- A remark on your code: `Field fields[] = classA.getDeclaredFields();` - the C-style of aray declaration is highly discouraged in Java. The array-brackets should be written after the type, not after the variable name: `Field[] fields = ...;`.

Comment: @Turing85 nope...this is a private class 
Please refer logs :
2018-12-26 12:38:04,857 INFO  [http-nio-8180-exec-4] [] [] [diy-CJ] []- fields are : private com.paytm.oe.entity.RelatedBusinessSolutionMapping com.paytm.oe.entity.UserBusinessMapping.relatedBusinessSolutionMapping

Comment: @Turing85thanks for the edit on fields!!
Please do help me with the class name

Comment: The JVM doesn't lie. If it tells you that this is the class name of the object, then this is the class name of the object. The object is an instance of a dynamic proxy class generated by javassist.

Comment: @JBNizet but this isn't the class name!
The characters "_$$_jvst3bb_5e" have been uselessly appended

Comment: It **is** the class name. Because you're using a framework that generates and uses dynamic proxies generated by javassist.

Comment: i am using spring framework but this isn't the class name for sure.
I can attach more loggers for your reference

Comment: If it wasn't the class name for sure, why would Java tell you that it is the class name? Have you seen somewhere in the javadoc that says "returns the class name, but sometimes with _$$_jvst3bb_5e appended just to annoy you"? It is the class name of the dynamic proxy generated by your framework (Hibernate probably). Just because you don't understand what proxies are and why they're used doesn't change that fact.

Comment: Could you please explain me what proxies are and what changes are to be done in code to go to the correct class instead of this class?

Comment: Google for "what are dynamic javassist proxies", click the first links, and read. The best way to solve your reflection problem is, most probably, to stop using reflection.

Comment: @JBNizet if i can apply checks for dynamic class generation with the help of javassist....could you please suggest me some kind of check for the same?

Answer (score 1):

As is pointed out in the comments the class your code is failing on is not because the class name is wrong but because it's a javaassist proxy class. As far as I am aware javaassist only proxies by creating subclasses so if you know the class is a proxy then you simply need to call `Class.getSuperclass()`. To retrieve the original class, javaassist proxies all implement the javassist `Proxy` interface so something like this probably does what you want:

```
Class<?> classA = object.getClass();
if(javassist.util.proxy.Proxy.isAssignableFrom(classA)) {
    classA = classA.getSuperclass();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your object should be a dynamic proxy target which generated by spring(I guess ,cuz there is no relative code).

then you can try this

```
Class clazz = AopUtils.getTargetClass(proxy);
Arrays.stream(clazz.getDeclaredFields()).forEach(field -> System.out.println(field.getName()));
```

AopUtils is under org.springframework.aop.support

Answer (score 0):

```
if (object instanceof HibernateProxy) {
            object = ((HibernateProxy) object).getHibernateLazyInitializer()
                    .getImplementation();
        }
```

**This piece of code worked for me!**